# Rails - Can't Render Footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assistance requested.  I can get my Header to show but not my Footer.

Here's the code:

```
  <body>

    <%= render 'shared/header' %>
    <%= render 'shared/alerts' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>

  </body>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: Not enough code here. What does your `shared/_footer.erb` file look like? What if, just as a test, you moved your `<%= render 'shared/footer' %>`, does it show up then? What elements are emitted at the end of the `yield`? Several different things could go wrong that aren't at all visible in the code you're showing. The problem may be in one of the pieces.

Comment: What is happening?  Can you see any of the DOM in the footer in the console?  Are you receiving an error?  What does your footer partial look like?

Comment: From the console: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___946931734_96445008'
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10450ms (Views: 10300.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: <!-- Footer -->
<footer class="footer text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
        <h4 class="text-uppercase mb-4">Location</h4>
        <p class="lead mb-0">2215 John Daniel Drive
          <br>Clark, MO 65243</p>
      </div>

Comment: I can't post the whole file or attach it that I can see...

Comment: I followed your advice and, 'yes,' the footer does appear when moved to the top of the logic.  So, I will play around with the browser settings.  Thanks for your help.